# How is wget able to download an iso file when only iso.gz is listed under the FTP library

Tags: ftp, iso-image, wget, solaris, gz

I hit a behavior of wget from FTP server (URL: ftp://foo.com/bar/...) that was unfamiliar to me. Can you direct me to some documentation or explain how is the following possible?

If I wget the folder's URL I get an `index.html` (shown at the bottom of the post) with the following listing which shows that only the zipped file is available: `os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso.gz`

I can wget this file's URL and I will get a gzip file with specific MD5 checksum.

```
c4fd702b3ad296561b2ec7e4b888e624  os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso.gz
os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso.gz:        gzip compressed data - deflate method , original file name
```

However I can also wget the same file URL omitting the `.gz` extension, leaving only the filename `os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso` and I will now get an iso file, which is not listed in the `index.html`.

```
08daf88aca95325c3aa9ae6406e02198  os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso
os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso:   ISO 9660 filesystem image
```

It's as if wget "knows" to extract the iso from the iso.gz file.

Is this what happens?
How does it work?

This is the content listed in the `index.html` for the folder:

```
2016 Apr 13 14:45  Directory   <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/.RE/">.RE/</a> 
2016 Apr 13 14:36  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/README.11.3.7">README.11.3.7</a>  (3097 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 14:36  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/md5sum-repo-iso-123_0.txt">md5sum-repo-iso-123_0.txt</a>  (63 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 13:02  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/md5sums.txt">md5sums.txt</a>  (321 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 09:52  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/os_image_123_0-ai-sparc.iso">os_image_123_0-ai-sparc.iso</a>  (570142720 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 09:53  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/os_image_123_0-ai-x86.iso">os_image_123_0-ai-x86.iso</a>  (496521216 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 13:02  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/os_image_123_0-fallback_boot-sparc.pkg">os_image_123_0-fallback_boot-sparc.pkg</a>  (103859114 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 14:37  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso.gz">os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso.gz</a>  (3613854717 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 09:52  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/os_image_123_0-text-sparc.iso">os_image_123_0-text-sparc.iso</a>  (885370880 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 09:53  File        <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/os_image_123_0-text-x86.iso">os_image_123_0-text-x86.iso</a>  (795648000 bytes)
2016 Apr 13 14:38  Directory   <a href="ftp://foo.com/bar/05/zipped-repo/">zipped-repo/</a>
```

---

Adding wget output.

```
[my_user 503 0 /tmp]$ wget ftp://foo.bar.com/products/Solaris_11/s11.3/support/sru07/05/sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso.gz
--2016-05-10 06:39:19--  ftp://foo.bar.com/products/Solaris_11/s11.3/support/sru07/05/sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso.gz
           => ‘sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso.gz’
           Resolving foo.bar.com (foo.bar.com)... 10.10.11.11
           Connecting to foo.bar.com (foo.bar.com)|10.10.11.11|:21... connected.
           Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
           ==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
           ==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /products/Solaris_11/s11.3/support/sru07/05 ... done.
           ==> SIZE sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso.gz ... 3613854717
           ==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso.gz ... done.
           Length: 3613854717 (3.4G) (unauthoritative)

           sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso.gz        100%[===========================================================================>]   3.37G  99.5MB/

           2016-05-10 06:39:56 (94.4 MB/s) - ‘sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso.gz’ saved [3613854717]
```

---

```
[my_user 505 0 /tmp]$ wget ftp://foo.bar.com/products/Solaris_11/s11.3/support/sru07/05/sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso
--2016-05-10 06:43:25--  ftp://foo.bar.com/products/Solaris_11/s11.3/support/sru07/05/sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso
           => ‘sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso’
           Resolving foo.bar.com (foo.bar.com)... 10.10.11.11
           Connecting to foo.bar.com (foo.bar.com)|10.10.11.11|:21... connected.
           Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
           ==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
           ==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /products/Solaris_11/s11.3/support/sru07/05 ... done.
           ==> SIZE sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso ... done.

           ==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso ... done.

           sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso               [                                                            <=>             ]   4.04G  32.3MB/

           2016-05-10 06:45:39 (30.9 MB/s) - ‘sol-11_3_7_5_0-incr-repo.iso’ saved [4337887232]
```

Comment: You wrote *"shows that only the zipped file is available"*, yes the listing just below shows `08daf88aca95325c3aa9ae6406e02198  os_image_123_0-incr-repo.iso`. Also I do not understand your two separate listings, both labeled `index.html`

Comment: Also what's the URL? Is it `ftp://` or `http://`? What the server is?

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl - I edited the post to make it more readable. It is a FTP:// server. It's an internal server at my workplace, so can't share it for anyone to try it themselves.

Comment: But what FTP server *software* that is?

Comment: I dont have this information.

Comment: A log file from any FTP client may show that. Actually a log file and a complete output of the `wget` may be useful.

Comment: Added the output of wget. log file doesn't contain additional information beyond that in the output I added.

Comment: OK, so try another FTP client. E.g. some GUI one, FileZilla or WinSCP.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely the server is configured to look for `.gz` file, when the requested file is not found and return an extracted contents.

With HTTP, it's probably easy to set this up with Apache `mod_rewrite` and `mod_deflate` modules. Not sure, if some FTP server supports this.